# how to change the bullet color in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

i am using the plugin of `tinymce` in my website

when i change the color of text, the bullet color remains black. 
i also try to edit the html code and put color in this code line

```
    <ul style="list-style-type: disc;">
<li style="list-style-type: none;">
<ul style="list-style-type: disc; color: #da000c;">
<li style="list-style-type: circle; list-style-position: outside;">
<span style="font-style: normal; list-style-type: circle;
 list-style-position: outside;
 color: #ff0000;">
<span class="example1">Blood</span><span class="example1"> cannot be manufactured.
 It can only come as a gift from people.</span></span></li>
```

anyone please tell me how to change the bullet color in tinymce..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when I input this into tinymce, I see a black box with a red list item inside it *with a red bullet*.:

```
<div style="background-color: black;">
  <ul>
    <li style="color: red;">aaaaa</li>
    <li>ccccc</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

That is with Chrome 18.0/Mac.  What browser are you using?  Try the above on Chrome, and let me know what you find.

Comment: thanks for the +1/acceptance.. so now, what did you find?  Did you figure out how to make bullets colored the way you want in the tinymce window?  Or you are still stuck?  Or you no longer care?  It is good to follow through until there is some kind of resolution, and then update your question/comment(s)/answer(s) to reflect the evolution of your thinking/discoveries in any threads you participate in, let alone the ones you start! Then readers will know you are serious, and will make the effort!, not to mention that these threads will then be more useful for others who find and read them.